# symfony/console input length

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-console

I am writing a symfony/console application (using v4 components) and I am running into an issue with input lengths on questions.

When asking for user input it appears I can only input upto 1023 characters? Is there a way to increase this - or is it something else effecting this?

Using OSX, iTerm2, PHP 7.1

Thanks.

EDIT: the question asks for a security token, which is a very long string - hence the need for more chars.

Comment: Are you expecting me to answer one question with more than 1023 character in the answer? Maybe you need to break the questions up a bit

Comment: The "question" takes a token key - which is very long, and would expect it to be pasted in and not typed at all

Comment: Potential workaround could be to store the token in a file and reference that in the question?

Comment: This doesn't explain the 1023 character limit, but it is worth noting that there is a limit to the input of 4095 bytes due to the maximum line length of 4096 in the unix terminal - as referenced in this [Symfony issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/47586)